# How do I use the MoqAutoMocker auto mocker with StructureMap 3?

Tags: moq, structuremap3

I'm trying to get familiar with unit testing with StructureMap, and am attempting to use the built-in auto mocker for Moq that appears to come with StructureMap. I installed the NuGet package [using the directions](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap)

```
Install-Package StructureMap
```

and it installed and SM working fine. The repository clearly [has the MoqAutoMocker code in it](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/tree/master/src/StructureMap.AutoMocking.Moq), but the *StructureMap.AutoMocker.Moq* namespace is nowhere to be found:

[image: The object graph I see to demonstrate the AutoMocker implementations don't appear to exist.]

I've checked out several examples that make this seem very easy to do, but they're a couple years old and seem focused on previous versions of SM, but I'm hopeful there's just something I don't see yet:

http://joelabrahamsson.com/setting-expectations-with-structuremaps-moqautomocker/
http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/10/automock-with-structuremap-and-moq.html

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: You'll need structuremap.automocking.moq package.
Check this out: [http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=structuremap.automocking](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=structuremap.automocking)

Comment: Sure enough it was that obvious! If you want to change this comment to be an answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need structuremap.automocking.moq package. Check this out: http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=structuremap.automocking